# Filtering text file and output to csv

Tags: unix, filter, filtering

I am using Solaris SunOS 5.10. I have a directory which I have populated with a number of text files. Something like this:

```
CMGW9.log
CMGW11.log
CMGW2.log
.
.
CMGWx.log
```

I am filtering only the interesting part from a file by using:

```
cat CMGW9.log | nawk '/productNumber|productRevision/'
```

The output I get is:

```
productNumber                        GMPV4_CNP_R6.3.2.0D
productRevision                      R6A
```

Now the requirement is a csv file like following:

```
|MGW_Name|   Product Number   |Product Revision|
------------------------------------------------

 CMGW9   GMPV4_CNP_R6.3.2.0D|  R6A           
 CMGW11   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  R6A
 CMGW2    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  R6A
 .   .  .   .   .   .    .   .  .
 CMGWx    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xx
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: That output is not a CSV file format. Are you sure you want CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a part of a possible solution;

```
$ cat getloginfo.sh 
#!/bin/bash
for file in CMGW*.log
do
  filename=${file%.log}
  pn=`awk '$0 ~ /productNumber/  {print $2}' $file`
  pr=`awk '$0 ~ /productRevision/  {print $2}' $file`
  echo -e "$filename\t$pn\t$pr" >> CMGWresume.log
done
$ ./getloginfo.sh 
$ cat CMGWresume.log 
CMGW11  GMPV5.3.2.0D    R6AB
CMGW9   GMPV4_CNP_R6.3.2.0D R6A
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It produces a CSV file.

```
awk -v OFS=, 'FNR == 1 { key = FILENAME; sub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", key); keys[++k] = key }
    /productNumber|productRevision/ { a[key, $1] = $2 }
    END {
        for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
            key = keys[i]
            print key, a[key, "productNumber"], a[key, "productRevision"]
        }
    }' *.log
```

And this may produce the table you presented:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR == 1 { key = FILENAME; sub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", key); keys[++k] = key }
    /productNumber|productRevision/ { a[key, $1] = $2 }
    END {
        print "|MGW_Name|", "Product Number", "|Product Revision|"
        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print
        for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
            key = keys[i]
            print key, a[key, "productNumber"], a[key, "productRevision"]
        }
    }' *.log
```

You can use `printf` instead of `print` to change the formatting.